# I need help to profile my code

Tags: perl

I need your help. Say I have a code inside a for statement similar to as shown below.

the value of $logCount is massive. Like a million. There are certain hashes that are made in my loop that grows over period of time, and it runs my system out memory!. What I am supposed to do is, run through the loop and then write the results to a file. But since I am running out of memory this never happens.  Hence I want to break my loop into steps of 1000.

Can you help? Is there a smarter way to do this? I dont know how to append to the bottom of the file, if I break my loop.

```
for (my $i=0; $i < $logCount; $i++){    
    # Crap code
    # Herp Derp
    generatePowerRecord($sectorMapper->{'sectors'}, \$powerresult, ,\%Dimensions, \@powers, \@Attn, $sectors, $count-$totalcount);
    generatePhaseRecord($sectorMapper->{'sectors'}, \$phaseresult, ,\%Dimensions);
    generateDelayRecord($sectorMapper->{'sectors'}, \$delayresult, ,\%Dimensions, \@delay_history, \$sectors, $count-$totalcount);
};

$fh->print($dataresult);
$fh->print($powerresult);
$fh->print($phaseresult);
$fh->print($delayresult);
$fh->print("\n}");
```

Comment: Show the full code. – The [append access mode](http://p3rl.org/opentut) is spelled `>>`.

Comment: Try it with smaller input data and look at what those subroutines are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to throw extra prints into your loop and call them every 1000th iteration, something like this:

```
for (my $i=0; $i < $logCount; $i++){    
    # Crap code
    # Herp Derp
    generatePowerRecord($sectorMapper->{'sectors'}, \$powerresult, ,\%Dimensions, \@powers, \@Attn, $sectors, $count-$totalcount);
    generatePhaseRecord($sectorMapper->{'sectors'}, \$phaseresult, ,\%Dimensions);
    generateDelayRecord($sectorMapper->{'sectors'}, \$delayresult, ,\%Dimensions, \@delay_history, \$sectors, $count-$totalcount);

    # call this every 1000th iteration
    if($i > 0 and $i % 1000 == 0) {
       $fh->print($dataresult);
       $fh->print($powerresult);
       $fh->print($phaseresult);
       $fh->print($delayresult);

       # cleanup hashes
       undef $dataresult;
       undef $powerresult;
       undef $phaseresult;
       undef $delayresult;
    }
};
```

The `print` call will append data to your file until it remains opened.

Comment: I used this. Except that I had to print each of them using different file handles and then later concatenate them all. But it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the highly-regarded [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aNYTProf) profiling module.

From the synopsis:

```
  # profile code and write database to ./nytprof.out
  perl -d:NYTProf some_perl.pl

  # convert database into a set of html files, e.g., ./nytprof/index.html
  # and open a web browser on the nytprof/index.html file
  nytprofhtml --open

  # or into comma separated files, e.g., ./nytprof/*.csv
  nytprofcsv
```

Comment: WOw. I have never heard of this module. Let me try and learn it. It will defintely be of use to me later.